# How do I add hours to a timestamp type field from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to add an hour to a timestamp format in php

this is what I have been trying this whole time:

in my database I have a field that's called ts, as in timestamp (it's a timestamp field that captures `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).
then I have in codeigniter a foreach to show my results. within my results I echo the ts variable but the hour that it captures is wrong so I want to change the time and add 2 hours.

this is the code that I have tried:

```
foreach($row as $reg){
    $timestamp = $reg->ts;
    $date = new DateTime($timestamp);
    $nTime = $date->modify('+2 hour');
    echo $nTime;
}
```

it gives me this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 4096Message: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to stringFilename: libraries/Table.phpLine Number: 353

Comment: You should solve this on insert, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor error in the use of the DateTime object.

```
foreach($row as $reg){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimestamp($reg->ts);
    $date->modify('+2 hour');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

You may want to use a different format for the date and time!

Comment: it's giving me 2 hours from the time of right now not the time of `$timestamp`

Comment: America/Mexico_City timezone

Comment: CDT (Central Daylight Time) UTC/GMT -5 hours

Comment: it's on a live server which I don't have control over. I called my provider but he tell me he can't change those setting

Comment: Sorry, just found the error on my part. I typed it in my code rather than copy & paste $timestamp as error $timstamp

Answer (score 2):

**Example of adding time to date**

```
$nTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+2 hours'))
```

> **Note** `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` used to set TIMESTAMP manually

---

**In Your case**

```
foreach($row as $reg){
    $timestamp = date_create('2016-08-16 01:30:00'); 
    $date = new DateTime(date_format($timestamp,"Y/m/d H:i:s")); // 2016-08-16 01:30:00
    $nTime = date_modify($date, "+2 hours");
    echo date_format($nTime,"Y/m/d H:i:s"); // Output will be 2016-08-16 03:30:00
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

You have mentioned **"variable but the hour that it captures is wrong"** in your question. This may be you have to set `date_default_timezone_set("Country/City")`

Comment: why would you try to answer this question with an entirely different one? the OP's problem is just a simple method use in a datetime class

Comment: @Ghost Seems now i'm related to his question. thanks for the tip

Comment: You might want to test that DateTime functionality. It dont work. You cannot initialize a DateTime object with a timestamp!

Comment: You cannot use a DateTime object in a `date()` function either specially not in parameter 1 where a date format string belongs

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks man. Now it fixed and working fine. tested as well